a compile-time way to test whether a template parameter T defines a (static) method of its own, not considering the ones defined by base classes of T
I use the static class version CRTP (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern) in my code. That is:
// Base class template using CRTP
template <typename Derived>
class Base {
public:
    // Static function that can be overridden by the derived class
    static void initialize() {
        Derived::initialize();
    }
};

// Derived class inheriting from the CRTP base class
class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
public:
    // Static member function with the same name and signature as the base class
    static void initialize() {
    }
};

Since the Base class is a template class, it might receive a template parameter which does not define initialize() function in which case Derived::initialize() will call the base class version of initialize() recursively, thus leading to callstack overflow.
My query is how to be able to check at compile time as to whether the template paramter in Base class defines an initialize() member function of its own without considering the initialize() present in Base class.
I did find many questions here on SO related to checking whether a function was defined by a template parameter but when I tried to use those (SFINAE), they reported initialize() was defined in the template parameter due to the base class from which the class represented by the template parameter inherited having a member function initialize().
What I want is a compile-time mechanism to test whether a template parameter defines a (static) method of its own, not considering the ones defined by any of the base classes from which the class represented by the template parameter inherits.
FYI, I use C++ 17 or before.

having the base call a derived function with the same name is a confusing design, people expect the derived to call functions with same name in base, not the other way around, although you can get it to work, you want to name it differently so that people aren't confused, if i have a function called Initialize in Derived the first line i would think to put in it is calling the base class's Initialize to "make sure my bases are initialized"

Without the check, there would be infinite recursion if Derived has no initialize() (ie the worst you get is a stack overflow, which isn't actually that bad as it is somewhat reliable to crash).
The difficulty is from Derived being not complete by the time Base gets instantiated. I suppose this can be worked around by a level of indirection. However, it is simpler to rely on a static_assert that fires when initialize() is instantiated (or similar1):
template <typename Derived>
class Base {
public:
    // Static function that can be overridden by the derived class
    static void initialize() {
        Derived::initialize();
        static_assert(&Derived::initialize != &Base::initialize);
    }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {};

int main() {
    Derived::initialize();
}

Live Demo
In case Base has more bases, you can add more conditions. In case Derived has more bases whose initialize() need to be ruled out, you should rethink your design.
1 SFINAE on the method would work as well. The issue is that you can only possibly detect the missing initialize() when the method is instantiated, not already when Base<Derived> is instantiated.

Thanks! Are you sure it works on C++ 17? I could not get it to compile on gcc 9.2 (supports C++ 17 AFAIK).
See my version of code here and here:
https://godbolt.org/z/YT3aPrTYG
https://onlinegdb.com/5_IbEk4BO

@AnuragSSharma in your godbolt link you are not enabling C++17, but you use a C++17 feature. And when I enable it the error is about constexpr if which is neither part of your question nor of my answer. Before looking into this further you should remove the macro. If it works without the macro it will also work with, but the macro makes the code so much more unreadable

@AnuragSSharma I mean it even fails for the case where the derived class does provide an initialize method https://godbolt.org/z/7frE68q6q. That issue is unrelated to the question you asked here. Well, not really "unrelated" but as I said before, its neither in your quesiton nor in my answer, imho it justifies to open a new question. Make sure to post a [mcve]

@AnurakSSharme well ok i understood the issue. It was difficult because in the faulty code alsmost everything is different from here. In a nutshell, the code does not work, because you try to check the condition before both classes are instantiated which cannot work.

Thanks for your efforts! btw, the questiion title as well as the text said "compile-time" since the classes in my case are static ones. Basically, I wanted a compile-time way to "branch" the code at run-time to handle the non-existence of the member function in the template parameter to avoid stack overflow due to infinite recursion ( I do mention call stack overflow in the question).
I think the premise of the question still stands - "a compile-time method required to detect whether a template parameter defines its own member function excluding the ones defined by it's base classes".

@AnuragSSharma this answer does explain how to make a compile time check. THe answer also explains that this compile time check can only be done when the type is complete. You cannot possibly check if a type has a method when the type is incomplete.

@AnuragSSharma did you look at the Live Demo? The issue in your code is something that comes in addition to what you show in the quesiton. I suggest to open a follow up question. Make sure to post a [mcve]

@AnuragSSharma btw yes you do mention a stackoverflow in the quesiton. The point i was trying to make is that one can consider to leave it at that and call it a day. Unit test will show. Not much can go terribly wrong, because it will crash right there at the place where the issue is, hence rather simple to detect and fix.

FWIW, the OP's program mostly works—macros and all—in the lastest version of MSVC. Compiler switches set to C++17: /std:c++17 /permissive- It skips the registration of ClientClass2, but it does not display the message Derived::initialize() not defined!

OK. I'll soon open a new question with whatever we've gleaned from this discussion. Thanks again! I'll post the question link here when I do.

On my own Visual Studio installation, rather than GodBolt, the OP's program runs correctly, and does display the message "Derived::initialize() not defined!!!" for ClientClass2. Hmm... Anyway, this answer got my up-vote.

@tbxfreeware its something about order and time of instantiation. Afaik msvc has always defered from how gcc does it in the details.

Adding description of static_assert makes this work with C++11 and quite old gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/qcsYoMsbs
